# Component instance as default prop

Tags: reactjs

I want to allow a component to pass in a button component or default to an instance created in the component.

Say I have a component like this:

```
const Form = ({ submitButton, children }) =>
  <form>
    {childrem}
    {submitButton || <OtherComponent/>}
  </form>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass button component to the props and simply use it in jsx:

```
const Form = ({ SubmitButtonComponent, children }) =>
  <form>
    {childrem}
    {SubmitButtonComponent ? <SubmitButtonComponent /> : <OtherComponent />}
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a good use case for ES2015 default function parameters:

```
const Form = ({ SubmitButtonComponent = OtherComponent, children }) =>
  <form>
    {children}
    <SubmitButtonComponent/>
  </form>
```

This should be semantically equivalent to the answer given above.